# Firebird Server 3.0 not run automatically after installation

Tags: installation, server, firebird, launch, firebird-3.0

I have used Firebird setup 3.0 (Firebird-3.0.10.33601_0_Win32.exe) witch the parameters:
`Firebird-3.0.10.33601_0_Win32.exe /SILENT /NORESTART /COMPONENTS="ServerComponent,ServerComponent\SuperServerComponent,DevAdminComponent,ClientComponent" /MERGETASKS="UseSuperServerTask\UseGuardianTask,AutoStartTask,CopyFbClientAsGds32Task"`

Everything installs OK, but service "Firebird Server - DefaultInstance" does not run automatically. Is there any parameter to run FB Server automatically after installation? I can't restart system because I'm calling FB from application and after this I have other things to do. But FB server has to work.

Comment: I recommend asking about this on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) rather than here. That said, at a guess, I think you're missing the `UseServiceTask` task.

Comment: Guardian must not be used unless you are on Windows NT 4. If you want to run Firebird Server immediately after installation it can be done by a separate command "net start" or "sc start".

Comment: use standard Windows commands to run the service after installation, either `net.exe start <service name>`  or  (WinXP+) `sc.exe start <service name>`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've already tried to run the program "instsvc", included in the Firebird binaries. Otherwise, it might be helpful:

http://www.destructor.de/firebird/instsvc.htm

Some examples from the reference are

**Install SuperServer with Guardian, auto-start on boot**

`instsvc install -g`

**Install ClassicServer, auto-start on boot**

`instsvc install -c`

**Start Service**

`instsvc start`
or
`NET START "Firebird Guardian - DefaultInstance"`

Comment: You can improve your answer by actually typing in the command required.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @RohitGupta!

Actually, "instsvc" is a program that can be executed with a significant variety of arguments, resulting in commands with very precise behaviors (e.g. using "guardian" or not). Thus, it is important to cite the reference.

Also, running a Firebird server as a service is quite a different approach than running it as an application on system start. That's the case for containers, for instance. In this case, using "instsvc" may or may not be an option, so the reference above could serve as clarification.

Anyway, thanks again =)

Comment: At the time I commented, your answer had been flagged as low quality, being a link only answer.  Links can disappear.  Which is why, to make this a good answer, it is best if you cite the reference as well as paste the essential part of the answer here.  You could give an example or you could just paste most of your comment in your answer.  :-)

Comment: I have done a bit for you to show you what can be done.  Please edit to suit.